# How to access Google Maps API v3 marker's DIV and its pixel position?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Instead of Google Maps API's default info window, I'm going to use other jQuery tooltip plugin over marker. So I need to get marker's DIV and its pixel position.

But couldn't get it because there are no id or class for certain marker. Only I can access map canvas div from marker object and undocumented pixelBounds object.

1. How can I access marker's DIV?
2. Where can I get DIV's pixel position? Can I convert lat-lng position to pixel values?

==
appended:

I also tried with below code, but it doesn't change when I scroll the map.

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var px = this.getMap().getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(this.getPosition());
    console.log("(" + px.x + "," + px.y + ")");
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't this question be marked accepted? It looks like your question was addressed.

Comment: @jeff -- you're editing questions that are over 2 years old, continually bumping them to the top of the Active list. The code is already properly formatted, making the colors pretty is a minor change and isn't necessary.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - This question has been viewed almost 19,000 times. I think someone will eventually find the syntax highlighting useful.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't really get why would you want to get specific div for marker? If you want to display tooltip then all you need is pixel position of markers anchor (and knowledge about size of marker and placement of anchor), not div element. You can always trigger opening and closing tooltip by hand when event occurs on google.maps side.

For getting pixel position of anchor of given marker you can use this code:

```
var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(
    map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
    map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
);
var worldCoordinateNW = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(nw);
var worldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());
var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point(
    Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x - worldCoordinateNW.x) * scale),
    Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y - worldCoordinateNW.y) * scale)
);
```

In `pixelDistance` you get offset of specific marker anchor counted from left upper corner of the map (and you can get it's position from `map.getDiv()` div). Why it works like this (or is there a better way?) you can read in [documentation of google maps overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/overlays.html#MapCoordinates).

Comment: Besides tooltip, I want to animate marker with jQuery and that's why I need to access marker's DIV. Now I know I can't access it through maps API v3 and need to reimplement marker class with OverlayView. :(

Comment: Does anyone have a decent reverse function?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Unfortunately my current work don't involve working with Google Maps. This answer was just what I had to develop myself in some project, but besides this I have not much experience with Maps.

Comment: The same thing, but more elaborate and with an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/VzYF6/).

Comment: Good fiddle @machineaddict but others beware: It breaks if the `#map` div isn't at the top left, see [here](http://i.imgur.com/fT3xcn6.png); I'm looking for a fix now.

Comment: @dukedave: you simply get the `top` of `#map` like this `jQuery('#map').css('top')` and add up to `fromLatLngToPoint` function. The `(worldPoint.y - topRight.y) becomes (worldPoint.y - topRight.y + jQuery('#map').css('top'))`. This is not tested! But you get the idea.

Answer (score 12):

```js
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);

var proj = overlay.getProjection();
var pos = marker.getPosition();
var p = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(pos);
```

You can now access your pixel coordinates through p.x and p.y.

*FOLLOWING ADDED POST COMMENT:*

The downfall of the overlay projection is that until it your map canvas finishes loading it isn't initialized. I have the following listener that will force whatever method I need to trigger when the map does finish loading.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', functionName());
```

In the mean time I use the following check to avoid any errors before it does draw.

```js
if(overlay.getProjection()) {
  // code here
}
```

Comment: If only this worked, it would be awesome. `overlay.getProjection()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: overlay.getProjection is initialized only after the map has loaded<br/><br/>To circumvent this and initialize it I have a listener that calls the function that uses it. I'll add the code to my comment up top.

Comment: Thanks so much for updating this for me! I already use the event listener, so I will be implementing this as soon as possible!

Answer (score 4):

One thing to remember when using MBO's code:
When the map tiles are repeated, `map.getBounds().getSouthWest()` returns "-180" independent of the map's position. A fallback I'm using in this case is calculating the pixel distance to the center instead of the upper left corner, since `map.getCenter()` seems to return the currently centered point in any case. E.g. (using jQuery):

```js
// Calculate marker position in pixels form upper left corner
var pixelCoordsCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getCenter());
pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point(
    Math.floor((pixelCoordsMarker.x - pixelCoordsCenter.x) * scale + $(container).width()/2),
    Math.floor((pixelCoordsMarker.y - pixelCoordsCenter.y) * scale + $(container).height()/2)
);
```

Comment: This should be close to the top, an extremely important feature for international-style maps. This snippet was the one that eventually corrected all of my positioning issues.

Answer (score 2):

anyone still looking for an answer to this, have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries
among some other useful google maps stuff there's RichMarker which allows you to add DOM elements of your choice as draggable markers. just add class/id to handle with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Rene's answer only gives you the "world coordinates" (that is, coords independent of zoom level and viewport). MBO's answer seems right, though, so that's the one you should accept and vote up (I can't as I just registered) as the solution might easily be overlooked otherwise.

As for an "easier" version, you can use the methods in MapCanvasProjection instead, but that means you'll have to make your own overlay. See [here](http://www.devcomments.com/Using-fromLatLngToDivPixel-in-v3-at141102.htm) for an example. :P

Answer (score 1):

MapCanvasProjection's `fromLatLngToContainerPixel()` is probably what the author's after. It will give you the pixel offset relative to the map's container. I did some experiments and found the "simplest" working solution. (I wish Google makes this feature more accessible!)

First you declare a subclass of `OverlayView` somewhere like so:

```
function CanvasProjectionOverlay() {}
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.constructor = CanvasProjectionOverlay;
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){};
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){};
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){};
```

Then *somewhere else* in your code where you instantiate the map, you also instantiate this OverlayView and set its map, like so:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapOptions);

// Add canvas projection overlay so we can use the LatLng to pixel converter
var canvasProjectionOverlay = new CanvasProjectionOverlay();
canvasProjectionOverlay.setMap(map);
```

Then, whenever you need to use `fromLatLngToContainerPixel`, you just do this:

```
canvasProjectionOverlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(myLatLng);
```

Note that because the MapCanvasProjection object will only be available once `draw()` is called, which is sometime before the map's `idle`, I suggest creating a boolean "mapInitialized" flag, set it to true on the first map `idle` callback. And then do what you need to do only after that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you MUST access the DIV, here's some code. Beware that this will only work with the standard marker (20x34px), and it'll find all markers. You might want to improve this hack to suit your needs...

**BEWARE! THIS IS A HACK**

```
var a=document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var b=a.getElementsByTagName('img');
var i, j=b.length;
for (i=0; i<j; i++) {
  if(b[i].src.match('marker_sprite.png')){
    if(b[i].style.width=='20px' && b[i].style.height=='34px') {
      c=b[i].parentElement;
      console.log(c.style.top+":"+c.style.left);
      // this is a marker's enclosing div

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working snippet jQuery style ready to copy/paste:

step 1 - initialize your map and options

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="get-your-jQuery" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="get-your-maps.API" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
var bucharest = new google.maps.LatLng(44.43552, 26.10250);
var options = {
zoom: 14,
center: bucharest,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}
```

As you can see, lower, the variable map is not preceded by VAR, because it should be Global as we use another function to get the fromLatLngToContainerPixel. For more details check [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures).

```
map = new google.maps.map($("#map_canvas")[0], options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: google.maps.LatLng(44.4407,26.0864),
map: map
});

new google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
          placeMarker( marker.getPosition(),'#tooltip');//param1: latlng, param2: container to place result
});

new google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
        $("#tooltip").css({display:'none'}); //this is just so you can see that all goes well ;)
    });

 overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
 overlay.draw = function() {};
 overlay.setMap(map);

}); //here ends jQuery.ready

function placeMarker(location, ID){
var containerPixel = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(location);
var divPixel       = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(location);
$(ID).css({top:containerPixel.y, left:containerPixel.x, 'dislay':'block'});
}
//--> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tooltip" style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; z-index:1; background:#fff">Here I am!</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px; height:300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it's easiest to assign a custom icon and use the img src attribute to get to the element. You can still use the default google maps icon, just save it locally.

```
$("#map img[src='my_marker.png']").getBoundingClientRect();
```

Answer (score 0):

For many circumstances the complex math used the calculate and change the pin position in the accepted answer may be appropriate.

For my particular use I just created a transparent PNG with a canvas significantly larger than I needed for the icon. Then I just experimented moving the pin around within the transparent background and applying the new image to the map.

[image: adjusting the pin offset in photoshop]

Here is the spec for adding the custom pin image, with examples:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

This method will definitely scale as an offset in pixels instead of an actual different long/lat even when you zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, got div by event.

```
marker.addListener("click", markerClicked);

function markerClicked(event) {
    // here you can get the marker div by event.currentTarget
}
```