# Clustering Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Could you please tell me how to find the pixel co ordinates of a marker in Google Maps API V3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878608/google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the latitude and longitude with `Marker.getLatLng()`. You then will have a `LatLng` object. Next you need to transform from geographic coordinates to pixel coordinates, and you do that with `Map.fromLatLngToContainerPixel`.

So:

```
var pixelPosition = Map.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getLatLng());
```

Comment: Nup, I got to find the pixel co ordinates of the marker, not in terms of latitude/longitude. I have to display a <div> content on mouseover of the marker. I'm able to do that partly right - the div is displayed on the top left corner of the map. How do I display it right next to each marker?

Comment: My code goes like this: (Label.js file)

var x=0, y=0;
function getLeft(obj)
{
if ('string' == typeof obj)
obj = document.getElementById(obj);
while (obj != null)
{
x += obj.offsetLeft;
obj = obj.offsetParent;
}
//return x;
}

function getTop(obj)
{
if ('string' == typeof obj)
obj = document.getElementById(obj);
while (obj != null)
{
y += obj.offsetTop;
obj = obj.offsetParent;
}
//return y;
}

Comment: Why don't you read my answer again? pixelPosition will hold the offsets of the marker in respect to the map containing div. You access them with pixelPosition.x and pixelPosition.y

Comment: Okay, now how do I display the <div> near the element itself?

Comment: append your div to the map container, then set yourDivEl.style.position = 'relative'; yourDivEl.style.left = pixels.x; yourDivEl.style.top = pixels.y;

Comment: The API allows you to create overlays. So you should consider reading the documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Alin,
I tried the method which u said but I don't seem to get it right:( Can u plz provide me the correct syntax to find the co ordinates?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674392/how-to-access-google-maps-api-v3-markers-div-and-its-pixel-position

Comment: Hi Alin,
It doesn't display the div next to the marker. Instead, it shows up on the top left corner only. What do I do??:(

Comment: You do some debugging and see where it fails. First check that the x and y are correct. I suggest using Firefox with Firebug and debug with console.log().

Comment: If I change the position of the div to relative its getting displayed further to the left - as a result only a part of the div is seen. The x and y seem to be correct only..

Comment: First of all make sure you have position relative/absolute/fixed on the container. Then you can position the child with position:absolute; and left and top offsets.

Comment: Yeah, the container is positioned as Absolute. So do I need to set the same position to the div too?

Comment: First of all you need to make sure the div is added as a direct child of the container. Then give position: absolute; left: 100px; top:100px; test with some fixed offsets to make if work first.

Comment: The div is a label control which is added through a Label.js file. And my map is placed inside the iframe of a certain window. I need to display the label taking into account the co ordinates relative to the iframe. Could you help me with that pls?

Comment: Yes. We went far outside the scope of a programming question. You should consider hiring a professional.