# Is it possible to embed a jQuery animated SPAN element into a Google Map at a specific latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is it possible to embed a jQuery animated SPAN element into a Google Map at a specific latitude and longitude? (Just like a map marker.)

Currently, I am using a jQuery plugin to animate a series of transparent PNG frames and then populate a span tag with those PNGs. (See the animation plugin here: http://blog.shynet.nl/post/2010/08/28/Alternative-to-animated-GIFs-AnimateImages-jQuery-Plugin.aspx)

My original idea was to use CSS to position the SPAN object on top of the map where I wanted it, but this solution will not work when the user drags the map. How can I embed this object into a map in a fashion similar to a map marker?

**My source code can be found on PasteBin here:** http://pastebin.com/MY0SfqXE

An example would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can embed. there are methods to map latlong to pixel value relative to map container. for this you have to create a custom overlay. see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674392/how-to-access-google-maps-api-v3-markers-div-and-its-pixel-position)

Comment: Thank you for posting this link! Upon reviewing the code, this solution is specific to retrieving the contents of a marker DIV, and not actually adding a DIV to the map. However, I could be reading this wrong. Would you mind clarifying your solution? Thank you again for responding! :)

Comment: I faced same problem long ago. and solve it using custom overlay. right now I don't have that code. .getProjection() method is not available in google's native  overlay. You have to create a custom overlay.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Do you know where I might find a VERY simple guide to using the custom overlays?