# Get marker coordinates relative to the screen Google Maps API v3

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

As far as I understand, jQuery cannot read Google Maps data. So is there a pure javascript way to get marker coordinates relative to the screen? (top(), left()). Thanks.

EDIT:  *Projection* class did this via toScreenLocation() method in API v2, but how would I achieve the same in v3 ?

EDIT 2:  I am using WebView from Android SDK to load the map.

For **answer** see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671206/997633

Comment: The method described in this post worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671206/997633

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
var point;
var pointIWant = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition(), point);
```

According to the [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), [google.maps.Projection.fromLatLngToPoint()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection) converts a latitude/longitude coordinate to a point on the screen.

Comment: weird but it doesn't work. It returns undefined on pintIWant even though I have an eventistener for the map to finish loading. (idle)

Comment: instead, i was able to get the desired result with fromLatLngToContainerPixel() method

Comment: projection.fromLatLngToPoint converts from LatLng to world coordinates (also known as the point plane). It doesn't give you any reference as to how this point relates to the current viewport.