# Using fromLatLngToContainerPixel() in google map api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add my custom div with marker in google map. However, when I use **fromLatLngToContainerPixel()** or **fromLatLngToDivPixel()** or **fromLatLngToPoint()**, it always says that **undefined**. In details, it's anonymous function.
I've already checked, 
[How to call fromLatLngToDivPixel in Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538681/how-to-call-fromlatlngtodivpixel-in-google-maps-api-v3)
[How to access Google Maps API v3 marker's DIV and its pixel position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674392/how-to-access-google-maps-api-v3-markers-div-and-its-pixel-position/6671206#6671206)
But, they don't work for me. What can I do?
Here is the code.
Outside of initialize(),

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);
```

And inside the initialize(),

```
google.maps.event.addListener(init_marker, 'click', function(){
      infoWindow.open(map, init_marker);
      var latlng = init_marker.getPosition();
      var px = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
  });
```

Comment: I've try to use "this.getMap.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng)" to replace "overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng)". And It works. So, is this a problem of overlay? Like I should listen to 'idle'? But I don't really understand it.