# Show pop-up near marker [google maps api]

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular6

How can I make this `popup` display right near `marker`?

This is what I have

.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="long" style="height: 350px;" [fitBounds]="true">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let data of locations; let i = index" [latitude]="data.lat" [longitude]="data.lng" [agmFitBounds]="true"
    (mouseOver)="clickOnMarker($event)" (mouseOut)="outsideMarker($event)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
<button id="openModalButton" [hidden]="false" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <li class="details">Item</li>
</ul>
```

.ts

```
  clickOnMarker(event) {
    document.getElementById("openModalButton").click();
  }

  outsideMarker(event) {
    document.getElementById("openModalButton").click();
  }
}
```

But the marker is displayed somewhere in the right corner of the page.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could be you need the position in pixel of the marker for place the modal ..  you could take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674392/how-to-access-google-maps-api-v3-markers-div-and-its-pixel-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try not to do this 'manually'. Use `agm-info-window`instead:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="long" style="height: 350px;" [fitBounds]="true">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let data of locations; let i = index" [latitude]="data.lat" [longitude]="data.lng" [agmFitBounds]="true">
    <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true">
         Hello world!
    </agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Hope it helps!